# I can't access my data from form across multiple pages

Tags: php, html

the problem is when i submit the data from a form i can access it in my homepage but if I click again my home button it states an error

here is my code

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require 'dbconnect.php';

    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = '".$uname."' AND password ='".$pword."'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    $url = "homepage.php";

    if ($numrows==1)
    {
        include("$url");
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('User not found, Please create one');document.location='index.php'</script>";
    }
?>
```

here is my homepage code

```
    <?php

        require 'dbconnect.php';
        
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pword = $_POST['password'];
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = '".$uname."' AND password ='".$pword."'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $numrows = $result->num_rows;

        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><a href='logout.php'><b>Log out</b></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='SlrSystem.html'><b>Solar System</b></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='about-us.php'><b>About Us</b></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='homepage.php'><b>Home</b></a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "<div class='home'>";
        echo "<h1 class='right'><b>EXPLORE<br></b></h1>";
        echo "<h1 class='left'><b>THE GALAXY FROM<br></b></h1>";
        echo "<h1 class='right'><b>YOUR COUCH</b></h1>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Form data in $_POST only exists in the same request after you submitted the form. Once the user is logged in, to have your system remember the fact that a login was successful, it's normal to add a value to the Session to indicate this. Then you don't need to worry about repeatedly asking the user for their credentials.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk (because plain-text passwords can be stolen by hackers). Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Hashed passwords cannot be decoded by anyone who steals them.

Comment: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (see above!). It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced or beginner programmer. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.

Answer (score -2):

// On the first page
document.cookie = "formData=yourData; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

// On the second page
const formData = document.cookie.split(';').find(cookie => cookie.includes('formData')).split('=')[1];

Comment: Saving the user's cleartext login information in a cookie that goes back to the browser is a terrible idea from a security viewpoint.